# Why in examples of git diff output I see a/file.txt b/file.txt but in reallity i see i/file.txt

Tags: git, git-diff

This is my `git diff`

```
diff --git i/app/Model/EntityFactory.php w/app/Model/EntityFactory.php
index 63cd40f..4ef95aa 100644
--- i/app/Model/EntityFactory.php
+++ w/app/Model/EntityFactory.php
```

Why there is `i/app/...` and `w/app/...`, what that means (the i, w letters) and why it differs from examples of git, where I would see `a/app/...` and `b/app/...`?

Thanks

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry there.  Comment deleted.  Due to timing, I'm guessing you downvoted a question of mine.. I didn't even vote on your post.  Shooting the messenger, ey?

Comment: Yep, I confess, sorry for being silly. I will remove my downvote (when server allows it), I really thougth you are just trolling here and felt angry. Again, it was silly. Please accept my appology.

Comment: Accepted, thank you.  As to the vote itself, unfortunately it cannot be removed this late after the vote.  I'll have to edit the post to allow you to do so, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Yes, that is true http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited If you care and t is not a problem for you, please edit your question, I will remove silly downvote instantly.

Comment: Removed, sorry again. Thanks and bye now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found the core reason for this.
It is because of use `git config --global diff.mnemonicprefix true` - "Tell git diff to use mnemonic prefixes (index, work tree, commit, object) instead of the standard a and b notation"

Answer (score 2):

I assume these prefixes have been set manually. Do the following to change them:

```
git --src-prefix=<prefix>
git --dst-prefix=<prefix>
```

Comment: Yes! That is it! I could not found this. Thanks!